What comes after the Proletarian revolution based on Marx ideas?
I've been recently studying Karl Marx's elucidations, including views on Historical and Dialectical Materialism, The Dialectics of Hegel, ETC, to a point where I can barely understand the concepts.
What I have sincerely came up with until now, especially by my indications of Vladimir Lenin sayings on the fact that Marx gathered the ideas of Materialism and Dialectical Materialism under one shell, is that based on Marxism, which recognizes a Deterministic essence to all the existence of the society is that the hitherto of the society, based on its Determined essence, shall be Divinable.
Since one of my biggest problems with understanding Marxism as a whole is that he indicates that the Proletariat Revolution would happen, and therefore class antagonism would fully vanish.
That profound statement is totally incompatible with the laws of Dialectics:

There shall always exist a negative, which is produced "by itself".

Therefore if class antagonism is going to stop, then due to Marx's own beliefs which sees the whole existence of humans and history through class, Determined and unchangeable, therefore is the history going to stop?
So throughout Marx's own life, did he hold any belief or prophecy, more sightseeing than the Proletariat Revolution?
Did Marx and Engels provide any explanation to this question?

Marxist thought is no great interest of mine, but is well on topic for this site.  Can some of you stop downvoting newcomers willy-nilly, no reason given?  If you think the question can be clarified a bit, please indicate how, and provide some constructive feedback, rather than unexplained downvotes.  Welcome aboard and +1.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica As I have already noted in a comment to their previous similar question - it is about philosophy, not politics (and there is an SE community for that). Marx had a broad range of views - his enemies would say that his delirium has nothing to do with politics, while his admirers would claim that he dubbed in politics, philosophy, history, economics, biology and lots of other subjects. In either case, just because a question is about Marx doesn't mean that it is about politics.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad Where do you draw the neat dividing line between the two? Like the overlap is ideology which is in it's theoretical conception a form of philosophy, but which undoubtedly has had and often still has impacted the political demands, goals and actions of various groups. So where would you draw that line?

I didn't downvote but agree 100% that this question should be migrated to Philosophy.

@haxor789 "This question does not appear to be about governments, policies and political processes within the scope defined in the help center."

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad And just because a question is about someone about whom not all questions are about politics, does not mean that it isn't about politics. You make no argument, other than a vague reference to a comment to an unspecified other question, for why this particular question about Marx isn't about politics; you merely note that this question is about Marx, note that it's possible for a question about Marx to not be about politics, and act like you've somehow made an argument.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad I would be hard-pressed to come up with a question more political (and hence fitting here) than this one. Marx is the political theorist of his century, perhaps ever. He is to political theory what Darwin is to biology. Obviously, fundamental theories have a philosophical dimension because they enable new insights into the mechanics and perhaps trajectories of the world. That does not make them any less fundamental in their field.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Marx was a philosopher, with amateur interest in politics, sociology, economics, etc. He had made no significant contributions to any of these disciplines. His claim to fame is based on the use of his writings by totalitarian regimes and anti-western propaganda.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad Funny; I'd contend that the claim that Marx made "no significant contributions to politics" (or political science) is based on western propaganda ;-).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I expected this kind of answer: western propaganda, illuminati, the elders of Zion, deep state - good old conspiracy theories... which are off-topic in this SE, since none can be proven. But if you can cite a mainstream tetxbook that outlines Marx' contributions to political theory, I am interested.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad You can't take a joke if you see one, can you. It's beyond me how you can say the man that single-handedly created the theory on which half the world bases their regimes (yes, bastardized, mutilated and falsified in excess -- but still!) made "no significant contribution to politics". It is simply and obviously wrong on every level.-- Regarding "mainstream text books": May I ask whether you would accept Russian or Mandarin? Or is it only mainstream if it was written in a West European language? That is: Mainstream to you?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica  the man that single-handedly created the theory on which half the world bases their regimes - I did acknowledged  this: His claim to fame is based on the use of his writings by totalitarian regimes and anti-western propaganda. I am familiar with Russian and Chinese writings on the subject... but as I don't consider the USSR and PRC as free, I regard these writings as propaganda rather than genuine research.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad While I'm not totally opposed to moving it to philosophy as the comparison between Hegel's and Marx's approaches to dialectics is mostly theoretical. The initial question of essentially "According to Marx what would happen after the revolution" is undoubtedly a matter of policy, it's asking about the asserted effects of a political proposal and as such is an answerable question with regards to politics, isn't it?

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad Also Marx has been a very influential figure not just in Russian and Chinese sphere of influence. He is one of the founding inspirations of sociology's conflict theory, proposed an improvement to the labor theory of value of Adam Smith, was politically active as an activist and leader of a socialist movement. The problem is that his proposed perspective of seeing sociology, history, economics and politics as effects of the relation within production, is at odds which the current academic approach of looking at all of these domains as their own microcosm...

@haxor789 firstly, what would happen after the revolution is hypothetical, and therefore off-topic. Secondly, it is not about policy (decisions made by governments), but about social evolution.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad ... While cherrypicking only the comments that fit a particular academic branch usually ends up misrepresenting and not useful. So despite being often quoted as influential and inspirational he's rarely quoted subsumed by one of these fields as their foundational figure, which are usually people who advanced those branches as their own science rather than as an appendix to another theory. Though the fact alone that countries quote him as reference for their states ideology makes him a relevant political figure worth asking what is original, what is fact and fiction.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad What is the outcome of a revolution is hypothetical, what people SAY is the outcome of a revolution is very much answerable. Like the proposed example of "what are the costs and benefits of a policy" is also about a future policy where the real costs and benefits can't actually be called beforehand as either the costs might increase or if the budget is fixed, the benefit might decrease. But you can very much open the books about the calculations that people cite as their reasoning.

Let's set aside Lenin for a moment and stick with 'pure' Marx. Lenin's view on socialism and revolution is a different kettle of fish.
The place to start, I think, is with Marx's core belief, that the state — or more broadly put the sociopolitical governing structure, however defined — should be subordinate to citizens, never superordinate. Government should serve, not rule. When a governing structure rules people, then the people who control the governing structure become a 'class' that naturally exploits the ruled people (perceived as other classes) for the benefit of the ruling class. This exploitation is the heart of the material dialectic. Classes are exploited by control of the means of production and given rulers are overthrown periodically as the exploitation becomes too severe; technological changes alter the dominant forms of production, creating new sociopolitical governing structures so that new classes replace the old as governing classes. Hunter/gathering clans develop farming and clan leaders are displaced by landed aristocracy; farming techniques advance and landed aristocracy is replaced by feudal fiefs; trade and early industry are developed, and the feudal system transforms into a mercantilist/colonial system where wealthy commoners overtake aristocrats; heavy industry brings in capitalism; global warfare capacity brings on statism; trans-state economies usher in corporatism; globalized labor exploitation raises socialism… The material dialectic is merely an interplay between who controls the means of production and how the means of production changes: who rules whom, and how, and how those relations evolve through exploitation and conflict.
Note: Marx framed it as a 'material' dialectic because he was frustrated with the impotence of 'intellectual' dialectics. Hegel is great and all, but ultimately Hegelian dialectics are just argumentation, and Marx didn't believe that any amount of logical persuasion would convince a ruling class that their exploitation of others was wrong, much less get them to change. The ruling class has to be supplanted, with bloodshed or without, and that supplantation is an inevitable outcome of the purely material forces of production and exploitation.
Now, the proletarian revolution is not a single event, but a repeated process once we reach the stage where laboring classes are globally opposed to being exploited in capitalism. The non-ruling classes will replace the capitalist class and set up a socialist state, where the state controls production as a proxy for the non-ruling classes. But these socialist states will all tend to develop a socialist class that rules, and new proletarian revolutions will replace such with new versions of the socialist state. The hope, ultimately, is to reach a point where the state is content to serve because no one (or everyone) controls it. At that point, the material dialectic reaches a final synthesis and ends.
The 'end of history' question is interesting, but open. The people who use that phrase mean to suggest that the history we read in books primarily recounts violence, victory, and to lesser extent innovation, at least where innovation produces some sort of victory. History (to their somewhat jaded minds) is stories told by those who win to explain why winning makes them good people. When there's no more exploitation, there's no more victory over others, and there's no need for such stories. History as currently written will cease. But people will still lead their lives, innovations will still occur, and all the little unrecorded histories of life will go on.  If we remember what Orson Wells said in "The Third Man":

In Italy for thirty years under the Borgias, they had warfare, terror,
murder, and bloodshed, but they produced Michelangelo, Leonardo da
Vinci, and the Renaissance. In Switzerland, they had brotherly love,
they had five hundred years of democracy and peace, and what did that
produce? The cuckoo clock.

Italy had history, Switzerland didn't. But the mistake lies in thinking that we need warfare, terror, murder, and bloodshed to produce greatness, or that if we do, that greatness is worth the cost to others. And you know… Cuckoo clocks are nice.

A very good answer +1. It's worth pointing out, too, that a revolution is still a revolution, even if it doesn't involve bloodshed.


But these socialist states will all tend to develop a socialist class that rules, and new proletarian revolutions will replace such with new versions of the socialist state.

AIUI Marx thought that the coercive arms of the state would simply wither away from disuse. In practice the "new class" of apparatchiks did emerge as you say, but that wasn't predicted by Marx.

I am a guy from the down, and I think better not to say, what to do with your cuckoo clocks. I want flying cars. Note, siding with the ruling class does not make you its member, and even if you are, the next step of the history will come for you all.

@PaulJohnson: As I recall (and I'll confess it's been a minute since I went into this in detail), Marx was fairly vague about post-capitalist society, merely suggesting a series of proletarian revolutions until the final classless society was reached. And honestly, a phrase like "the coercive arms of the state would [...] wither away" sounds a bit later: more like Gramsci or one of the other structural Marxists that emerged separate from Engels and Lenin. But I could be wrong about that…

@GraySheep: "a guy from the down"... Down-under? Down South? Down stream? Goose down??? And how do you know you don't already have a flying car? Have you tried to make it fly? Seems like some experimentation is in order… Try driving off a pier: that way you can tell if you got the flying package or the submersible one.

"The hope, ultimately, is to reach a point where the state is content to serve because no one (or everyone) controls it." -- what's the envisioned process through which that happens, though? Did Marx believe that continued revolutions would "ratchet" the state's tendency to serve the people, or just that after rolling the dice (and the heads) enough times, we'd get lucky?

@Sneftel: My (personal) sense is that Marx was more of a social theorist than a purely political or economic philosopher. As I see it, each proletarian revolution would deepen and solidify people's understanding of social liberty and the proper purpose of governance. Eventually most people would find the effort to gain power over others distasteful, and those few who still tried would find little support. There's echoes of Madison there: tyrants need factions to have traction, but being factional means surrendering liberty. If no one wants to do that, tyrants make no gains.

I suppose that Marx would have been the first to agree that future -- unimaginable -- technological and hence production progress would lead to future -- equally unimaginable -- corresponding new forms of society, culture and institutions, the "Überbau". Sure, class war which is rooted in scarcity would end; but history would not. The dialectic evolution of the means of production and society/culture would continue.  I don't think he would have agreed to a notion of an "end of history", even though the Heraklit/Hegelian driver of the class war is resolved.

@TedWrigley Do you have some quotes from Marx on that? That sounds more like something a reformist/evolutionary contract theorist would hypothesize. Like the king is king because we agreed he is king and he signed the contract stating their and our rights. And future king needs to succeed the old king, bartering for our approval by granting us more rights than what we are accustomed to until being king is so restricted that it barely has any meaning at all. Like that's also a way to reduce social inequality, but that's not revolutionary, but accepting of a status quo so reformist?

@haxor789: Can you be more specific on the 'that' you used in the first line? I'm not sure if you're referring to my speculation in comments or something in the main answer.

@TedWrigley Sorry my bad the concept of the revolution as a continuous cycle, so mainly the 2nd paragraph after "Note:" in your main answer.

@haxor789: You might look at this article, which spells it out in a more scholarly way than I can do at the moment. It seems to come mainly from "The Critique of the Gotha Programme",though I had remembered the source differently.  As I said, It's been a minute since I read all this, and there's doubtless some drift.

@TedWrigley Thanks for the article, I'll have a look at it when I find the time. Though from the first impression it's rather sketchy. Like for a start Marx died in 1883 and he's credited as first author for books as late as 1989 also it sound much more Lenin influenced, but I'll check on it later.

@haxor: I suspect those later are compilations of his unpublished writings post mortem; that's a fairly common practice.  But I'll have to look into it further myself.

@TedWrigley 1/ Ok after having read the paper and the Critique of the Gotha programe: Yeah kinda. Apparently Marx had sent that Critique to the parts of the SPD that he thought were his pals, but  they didn't like it and kept it in the locker, while Bismark criminalizing socialism would have made it a dick move to publish a critique when the movement was already under fire. But when those laws were lifted and the SPD got a new program Engels published these remarks post-mortem in 1891, minus the profanities. The citations are probably later editions though obviously not by Marx or not 1980...

@TedWrigley 2/ Also afai can tell Marx doesn't make the distinction between socialism and communism as different stages (at least not in the manifesto or the CotGP which are sourced), which afaik is an invention of Lenin. He speaks of the SPD proposal for labor vouchers though as a lower stage of communism as it clearly bears the marks of thought of a capitalist society while trying to overcome it. And argues that hiccups like that are likely inevitable. And apparently believes the liberal mantra that if the individual is freed the productivity increases and hence the necessity for that fades.

@TedWrigley 3/ And the entirety of the justification is of the Lenin's dictatorship is this unabridged quote: "Between capitalist and communist society there lies the period of the revolutionary transformation of the one into the other. Corresponding to this is also a political transition period in which the state can be nothing but the revolutionary dictatorship of the proletariat." Seriously that's all. And worse of all he doesn't even go into detail about how the class struggle against a capitalist class would look like, because in his rational Germany 1875 wasn't even there yet.

@TedWrigley 4/ To him "the state" (in Germany 1875) is an oppressive military despotism, ruled by a monarch with some capitalist influence and a very restricted parliament. And the demands of that communist party are so little audacious that they don't even call for utopian goals already realized elsewhere like "sovereignty of the people", so a democratic republic like Switzerland or the U.S. where the power comes from the people. So rather than dismantling or taking over the state for the people they petition it and put their fate in it's hands.

@TedWrigley 5/ While he argues that the role of the state as oppressor would seize through "sovereignty of the people" and the role of the state as backbone of capitalism would seize through a change in the production process, so not by equal outcome, but by ownership of the means of production. So what role a state could serve outside of that would be determined "scientifically", so to be determined i guess. Nowhere can I find a reference to a particular system or government or a perpetual revolution, can you?

I guess the people in the comments have a point and this, especially the Hegelian parts, are better suited within the philosophy stack.
Though as far as I understand it (which disclaimer is not a lot), Marx prided himself turning Hegel upside down and rather than explaining reality from ideas and consciousness, he tried to explain reality out of itself, so via a materialistic approach to dialectics.
So he intended that to become some sort of "science". Now I'm not well versed in that, it's 19th century "science" (so pretty early on), there are some interesting ideas, but also lots of things have been debunked and the whole dialectical approach allowed for developing theories, including both an effect and its opposite, that have been developed into unfalsifiable pseudosciences (Marx already did that, but especially implementations of "socialism/communism" apparently used that a lot to make the facts fit a philosophy rather than the other way around). So take any of that with a grain of salt.
That being said, it would at least explain, why this vanishing of class antagonism isn't a problem for him. It's not the idea (class antagonism) that creates the reality, it's the reality (production processes and relations) that creates the idea. Change the material conditions and you change the idea.
And apparently Marx was some sort of "libertarian" (in the original sense, not what people in the U.S. claim to be) who thought that the proletarian revolution would liberate people from their determinism and give them actual freedom, because they are no longer trapped in the determinism of class antagonism.

When, in the course of development, class distinctions have disappeared, and all production has
been concentrated in the hands of a vast association of the whole nation, the public power will
lose its political character. Political power, properly so called, is merely the organised power of
one class for oppressing another. If the proletariat during its contest with the bourgeoisie is
compelled, by the force of circumstances, to organise itself as a class, if, by means of a
revolution, it makes itself the ruling class, and, as such, sweeps away by force the old conditions
of production, then it will, along with these conditions, have swept away the conditions for the
existence of class antagonisms and of classes generally, and will thereby have abolished its own
supremacy as a class.
In place of the old bourgeois society, with its classes and class antagonisms, we shall have an
association, in which the free development of each is the condition for the free development of
all. (Last paragraph in "Proletarians and Communists" from communist manifesto)

Essentially his idea seems to be that, unlike previous revolutions where one class (people in the same material conditions) dominated another class, in the proletariat revolution, it would be the first time that a MAJORITY CLASS would win decisively and if it would do away with the conditions of production that exploited them by making things public property, than who's left to be exploited? Like the former capitalists aren't plenty enough and without capital they are basically proletariat themselves. Also 1 manager can exploit 100 workers, but 100 managers couldn't exploit 1 worker. So they would need to DIY the work anyway. Though luckily industrialization already meant overproduction, which is a problem for capitalism, but awesome for everyone else, you can get your needs met and can freely pursue whatever goals you have.
So once the proletariat has won and used its majority power to coerce the capitalists into giving up their property and dispersing it among everyone and taking equal turns working it, that power is becoming useless because there's no other class left to wield it against. So the only class it could be used against is itself and you wouldn't find a majority for that in a society where people are essentially in the same position, making them exploiter and exploited at the same time. So rather than class antagonism you'd, you'd have a situation where every individual is equal to every other individual (in class), so the voice of every individual matters equally. Meaning rather than political power of the class, you'd have a direct democracy, where individuals either halt each other or progress together, by allowing each other their individual freedom.
So afaik Marx didn't talk much about what comes after the revolution, because that would no longer be deterministic and people would need to figure that out by themselves. Though given the quote he seems to have had the idea that it would correlate with what people had already floated as "communism" previously (classless, stateless, ...).
Now for a guy who's vigorously anti-utopian, that is pretty damn optimistic. Afaik he also believed that capitalism would end religion, nations, races and so on because all of these things will become negligible with respect to class and so far capitalism hasn't delivered and it seems people can, unfortunately, hold on much longer fighting us vs them battles than Marx expected.
